dynamical tailwind class not activated in vue3
I have a problem with a dynamic tailwind class in vue3.
The thing is, it worked perfectly, and suddenly the animation isn't triggered. The class is supposed to be activated at a certain value in the store. But nothing happens.
Is there a setting in tailwind that needs to be activated for this? What could be the reason?
:class="{'-left-[750px]' : store.state.page==='1'}"

needs more debugging details.  first, what store?  pinia?  is the store value within the template reactive? if it is you should at least see the class added in the DOM.  if it's not in the DOM, then it's a problem with the class binding and/or reactivity.  if it is in the DOM, then it's a tailwind problem.  need to at least narrow the problem down.

Very abstract question indeed. Be sure about the CSS part first, Vue/Tailwind might not be the issue here as a whole.
